# Mongoose Aggregate and connect foreign Keys

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have two documents.

The first one is the `master` collection:

[image]

The second collection is the `stat` collection:
[image]

I sum up the recodes in the `stat` table with aggregate, when I'm doing that I want to use the foreign key and get the title from the `master` collection.

Following is the code I have used:

```
const totalClicks = await StatModel.aggregate([
  { $match: { campaignId: id } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { $dateToString: { format: '%Y-%m-%d', date: '$createAt' } },
      count: { $sum: 1 },
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'campaign.channels',
      localField: 'channel',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'channel',
    },
  },
  { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
]);
```

Output comes as follows:

```
[{"_id":"2022-06-04","count":8,"channel":[]}]
```

The desired output is:

```
[{"_id":"2022-06-04","count":8,"channel":"General"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this to get the title from populated channel,

```
const totalClicks = await StatModel.aggregate([
    { $match: { campaignId: id } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { $dateToString: { format: '%Y-%m-%d', date: '$createAt' } },
            count: { $sum: 1 },
        },
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'campaign.channels',
            localField: 'channel',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'channel',
        },
    },
    { $addFields: { channel: { $arrayElemAt: ['$channel', 0] } } },
    { $project: { _id, 1, count: 1, channel: '$channel.title' } },
    { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
]);
```